# There is no receivable account defined to make payment

Tags: point-of-sale, odoo-9

I want to use "point of sale" module in odoo-9 but i get error.  I have created 2 company and i did configuration.(i am not sure)  Then, when i confirmed the payment ,i get error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 605, in _handle_exception
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 642, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in _call_function
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 309, in checked_call
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 893, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 471, in response_wrap
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 892, in call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 884, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 238, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\openerp\addons\point_of_sale\point_of_sale.py", line 765, in create_from_ui
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 238, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\openerp\addons\point_of_sale\point_of_sale.py", line 720, in _process_order
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 238, in wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 9.0-20151221\server\openerp\addons\point_of_sale\point_of_sale.py", line 1040, in add_payment
UserError: (u'There is no receivable account defined to make payment.', None)
```

How can i solve this error?
Thank you.

Comment: I solve it .Settings > Parameters > Company Properties add  property_account_receivable

Comment: Hi, could you explain more on adding the property. What should i put in Field, Type, Resource and Value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Buket mentioned, quick answer is: Settings > Parameters > Company Properties add property_account_receivable
However, it is unclear what are the values.

Let me explain in detail:

1) Turn on debug mode

2) Go to Settings > Parameters > Company Properties

3) Click Create, you will see Create new property page

4) In the name section put in: "property_account_receivable_id"

5) Field section click on the drop down and select search more

5.1) Search for "property_account_receivable_id"

5.2) If it shows many items, select the one in Contact model

5.3) Click Create

6) Click Save.

You can do the same for Account Payable
In that case create the property with name "property_account_payable_id"
Then the field is Account Payable (with the same Contact model)